# Prevent duplicate items being added to cart in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using a session array to store products in a cart.

If the selected product is already in the cart, instead of the product being added again, I want to display a message informing the user that the product has already been added.

I've tried looping through the array to find the matching key. I've also tried the in_array($var1,$var2) function. With these, the status tells the user their product is already in the cart but adds the product anyway.

The last thing I tried was the array_search function to check if the key exists but the product is still getting added to the cart regardless.

```
if(isset($_GET['productID']) && $_GET['productID'] != "") {
    $product = $_GET['productID'];

    $product = (string)$product;

    $result_product = GetSpecificProduct($product);

    if(!empty($result_product)) {
       $cart_array[$result_product['ProductID']] = array(
          'ProductID'=>$result_product['ProductID'],
          'ProductName'=>$result_product['ProductName'],
          'Price'=>$result_product['Price'],
          'Specifications'=>$result_product['Specifications'],
          'CO'=>$result_product['CO'],
          'CatID'=>$result_product['CatID'],
          'Name'=>$result_product['Name'],
          'Quantity'=>1
       );

     }

    if(empty($_SESSION['tocoto_cart'])){
       $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'] = $cart_array;
       $status = $result_product['ProductName']." added to your cart.";

    }else if(!empty($_SESSION['tocoto_cart'])) {

      $key = array_search($result_product['ProductID'],$_SESSION['tocoto_cart']);

      if($key !== false) {
         $status = "Selected product is already in your cart.";
      } else {
         $status = $result_product['ProductName'] . " added to your cart.";
         $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'] = array_merge($_SESSION['tocoto_cart'],$cart_array );
}
```

Comment: If you can write a shopping cart you should know how to not add a product again. However, if you used someone elses cart you might not know this. The question is therefore: Which shopping cart are you using?

Comment: Its a cart functionality I created using php and sessions

Comment: Just need to be sure . Are you sure that this is the only thing you are using to add stuff to the cart ``  $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'] = array_merge($_SESSION['tocoto_cart'],$cart_array);``

Comment: Show the entire function, the problem is outside what you have showed.

Comment: what is your base to searching the duplicate upon your product storage?

Comment: Im creating an associative array that holds the products details. The key for the associative is the productID. I then merge the array to the session array. When i search through the session array im searching to find the matching productID. If the productID matches i dont want the product to be added. (Hope this makes sense)

Comment: array_merge does not merge arrays recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do something like this

```
$array = $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'];

$key = array_search($result_product['ProductID'], array_column($array, 'ProductID')); 

if($key !== false) {
    $status = "Selected product is already in your cart.";
} else {
    $status = $result_product['ProductName'] . " added to your cart.";
    $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'] = array_merge( $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'], $cart_array );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad approach to store cart items in session, because when server (or php-fpm/apache process) restarts, all carts will be cleared with the sessions.

Store cart items in DB, and to be sure that item is unique within the single cart use combined unique constraint on `user_token`, `cart_id` and `item_id` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 1` SQL

If this is too complex for you, try to modify this piece of your code

```
$key = array_search($result_product['ProductID'],$_SESSION['tocoto_cart']);
if($key !== false) {
```

to

```
if (array_key_exists($result_product['ProductID'],$_SESSION['tocoto_cart'])) {
   $_SESSION['tocoto_cart'][$result_product['ProductID']]['Quantity'] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Tried the second method you suggested but still had the same problem. After thinking about your first suggestion it makes sense and it does seem like a better approach. Thank you for the help.